# How to backup a filestream database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

1.) How can I backup my `FILESTREAM` database on SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server Management Studio?
2.) Do I have to make a separate backup of the `FILESTREAM` folder on disc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1.) You can backup the filestream data using the normal [SQL Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) & Recovery process. See [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) for reference. You can also exclude filestream data explicitly from your backup should you want to.

2.) You can take a separate backup of the filestream directory, but you really don't need to. It only makes sense to the SQL Server DB instance that created it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply SilverNinja. I followed what you advice & end up with a single backup file.Does that contain my filestream data as well ? I was following this article previously http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1854/how-to-backup-and-restore-a-sql-server-filestream-enabled-database/